# Query to return all results where a specific character is in the 4th position of a string

Tags: sql, string, position, substring, teradata

I have a table that contains 6 digit ID numbers ('AB1E11' for example) and I need to build a query in Teradata SQL that returns all results where 'E' is in the fourth position of the string. I haven't had a reason to do anything like this in several years, so I am extremely rusty. I know how to filter the results so that 'E' is contained anywhere in the string ( using SELECT * WHERE PLANID LIKE '%E%'), but I'm not sure how to filter the results so that only the ones where 'E' is in the 4th position show up. Can anyone help me out with this? I tried searching several times but couldn't find an answer.

Thank you.

Comment: Is there any way of doing this for an int datatype column, i.e. return records for a column where the 1st; or 5th and 6th; or 7th and 8th positions contain a 0?

Answer (score 3):

Just use `LIKE` with the `_` wildcard:

```
where planid like '____E%'
```

Note:  that is 4 underscores, which represent any single character.

Comment: Excellent, that worked perfectly. Thank you very much.

Comment: @sagi . . . Yes.  ANSI SQL defines `'_'` and `'%'` as the wildcards for `LIKE`.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT planid WHERE CHARINDEX('E', planid) = 4;
```

The starting position returned is 1-based, not 0-based.